# How to import data from Excel sheet to database in c# with LINQ?

Tags: database, linq, import-from-excel

I have three columns in Excel sheet such as id, name, family.
I am using LINQ and i need to import data from Excel to database with coding instruction, i have 6500 records in Excel sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your answer.
I found my problem. Here is the code :

```
        string pach = @"D:\C# Projects\ex.xlsx";
        var excelData = new ExcelQueryFactory(pach);
        var data = from x in excelData.Worksheet<xlsdata>("MySheet")
                   select x;
        DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            db.tbl_infos.InsertOnSubmit(new tbl_info
            {
                id = d.id,
                name = d.name,
                family = d.family
            });
        }
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to get all the data and then you can convert form DataTable to List. for below example to work you have [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255)
 should be installed

```
 public static DataTable ReadExcelWithoutOffice(string filePath)
    {
        var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;TypeGuessRows=0;FirstRowHasNames=true;ImportMixedTypes=Text\""; ;
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            var sheets = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] ";

                var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                var ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                return ds.Tables[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it gives me an error. "There is no row at position 0." in line 11. In the meantime,should I change the amount "TABLE"on line 8??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import and reference OpenXML, open the sheets, sheet, worksheet, IIRC - then parse through your columns into strings.

[OpenXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)

Then create a SQL Data Adapter and all of that, to use either a ConnectionString or SQLConnection, fire up a parameterized query, and it's in the database.

[SQL Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823854/How-to-connect-SQL-Database-to-your-Csharp-program)